# Javascript code doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, html

My javascript code just won't work. If I simply put `<script>alert("alert");</script>` in my code, it works as normal, but the big chunk of script in the following code is seemingly ignored. The code is meant to submit a hidden form when the use clicks a link. Is this a simple missing curly brace, or something more difficult?

The Code follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function $_GET(q,s) {
    s = (s) ? s : window.location.search;
    var re = new RegExp('&amp;'+q+'=([^&amp;]*)','i');
    return (s=s.replace(/^\?/,'&amp;').match(re)) ?s=s[1] :s='';
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days)
{
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
    return dat;
}

function stripGet(url) {
  return url.split("?")[0];
}

function load() {

alert('load');
document.getElementByName('link').onclick=onsubmit;

if($_GET('l') === "penguin"){
setCookie('expiry', new Date.addDays(30), 400);
setCookie('expired', 'FALSE', 30);
window.location = stripGet(window.location);
}
}

function onsubmit(){

alert('on submit');

if (new Date() > new Date(getCookie('expiry') || getCookie('expired') == 'TRUE') {
alert("expired");
setCookie('expired', 'TRUE', 1000);
window.location ='???';
return false;
}
else {
alert("valid");
document.getElementByName('username').value = atob('???');
document.getElementByName('username').value = atob('???');
document.forms['form'].submit();
return true;
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="load()" bgcolor="green" top="45%" align="center" link="orange" active="blue" visited="orange">

<form name="form" action="submit.php" method="POST">
<input name="__formname__" type="hidden" value="loginform">
<input name="username" type="hidden">
<input name="username" type="hidden">
</form>

<a name="link" href="javascript:onsubmit();" onclick="alert("click"); onsubmit(); return true;">
<h1 style="font-size: 84pt; padding-top: 1.5cm">
Submit form
</h1>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get errors reported in the browser's console?

Comment: The last function does seem to be missing a curly bracket. Indent your code property.

Comment: Debugging help questions require a [mcve] as per the [help]. Your code is not minimal. Please [edit] your question to make sure that your code is Minimal (only the code necessary to reproduce your issue in your question), Complete (users do not need anything else to reproduce your issue), and Verifiable (the provided code does reproduce the exact issue you are facing). As it is your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Note that this is also a common [downvote reason](http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/TooMuchCode).

Comment: Sorry. I thought that it might be useful, but if it's a few missing brackets, then this question will be removed

Comment: It's not fair. I post a question, it turns out to be a crap question, but I cannot remove it. This is hammering my reputation.

Answer (score 2):

This section

```
if (new Date() > new Date(getCookie('expiry') || getCookie('expired') == 'TRUE') {
```

is missing a closing parenthesis for the if statement.

That whole function needs some syntax work, so the below should fix it.

```
function onsubmit() {

  alert('on submit');

  if (new Date() > new Date(getCookie('expiry') || getCookie('expired') == 'TRUE')) {
      alert("expired");
      setCookie('expired', 'TRUE', 1000);
      window.location = '???';
      return false;
    } else {
      alert("valid");
      document.getElementByName('username').value = atob('???');
      document.getElementByName('username').value = atob('???');
      document.forms['form'].submit();
      return true;
    }
  }
```

As mentioned in a comment above, there were indeed console errors caused by your code. Be sure to check those first and you'll quickly find out why something isn't working.

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm trying to write this in using mobile safari. Even desktop safari lacks inspect element functionality, so I really don't have correct tools.

Comment: Desktop Safari does indeed have dev tools, they just aren't enabled by default. If you want to turn them on then open Safari's preferences, clicked Advanced, and then check the box next to 'Show Develop menu in menu bar'.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at your javascript console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
page.html:70 Uncaught ReferenceError: load is not defined
page.html:79 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
(program):1 Uncaught TypeError: onsubmit is not a function
```

Your code is missing some brackets in the function "onsubmit()".

```
function onsubmit() {
    alert('on submit');

    /* ')' was missing at the end of the if-clause! */
    if (new Date() > new Date(getCookie('expiry') || getCookie('expired') == 'TRUE')) { 
        alert("expired");
        setCookie('expired', 'TRUE', 1000);
        window.location ='???';
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("valid");
        document.getElementByName('username').value = atob('???');
        document.getElementByName('username').value = atob('???');
        document.forms['form'].submit();
        return true;
    }
} // <- '}' was missing here!
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't have a javascript console

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing parameter in your very last "if" statment . Follow below :

Your code

```
if (new Date() > new Date(getCookie('expiry') || getCookie('expired') == 'TRUE') {...}
```

Error: `new Date(getCookie('expiry')`   <--- missing closing parameter ")"

Corrected Code :

```
if (new Date() > new Date(getCookie('expiry'))|| getCookie('expired') == 'TRUE') {...}
```

Working code here : http://codepen.io/theConstructor/pen/EKWvyJ?editors=1010

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to debug your code to determine errors.
I found an error but I don't know if it's the only one:

```
function load() {

alert('load');
document.getElementByName('link').onclick=onsubmit;
```

It's getElementsByName so it's Elements not Element and also you need to choose which element of them you are targeting so if there is only one element with the same name then you can call it like that:

```
document.getElementsByName('link')[0].onclick=onsubmit;
```